# Django ValidationError date format exception

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi I check all question about my answer and doesn't find solution. Today I change my CustomUser model and then it stop works. I think, I failed one thing, when django ask me about default value to datefield and I add "" (empty string), but I not sure.
I tried to delete all db tables and migrate again, tried delete all migrations and still don't work
My model:

```
  class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('You must set email ')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('User must have username')

        user = self.model( username=username, 
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

 class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    alphanumeric = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$', message='Only alphanumeric characters are allowed.')

    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30, validators= [alphanumeric])

    email = models.EmailField(
        'Email',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True
        )
    avatar = models.ImageField(
        'Avatar',
        blank=True,
        upload_to='user/avatar',
        default='user/default.jpg'
        )
    firstname = models.CharField(
        'First name',
        max_length=40,
        blank=True,
        )
    lastname = models.CharField(
        'Last name',
        max_length=40,
        blank=True,
        )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(
        'Date of birth',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        )
    register_date = models.DateField(
        'Register date',
        auto_now_add=True,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        'Active',
        default=True
        )
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(
        'Superuser',
        default=False
        )

    def age(self):
        x = date.today()
        if self.date_of_birth.year is None:
            return ''
        else:
            return x.year - self.date_of_birth.year     

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = UserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'
```

my server log:
Running migrations:

```
 Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying users.0008_auto_20151104_1042...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ivan/diabetes_django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ivan/diabetes_django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ivan/diabetes_django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ivan/diabetes_django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 444, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ivan/diabetes_django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 222, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/ivan/diabetes_django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/ivan/diabetes_django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 148, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/ivan/diabetes_django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/ivan/diabetes_django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 201, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/home/ivan/diabetes_django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 484, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/home/ivan/diabetes_django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 567, in _alter_field
    new_default = self.effective_default(new_field)
  File "/home/ivan/diabetes_django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 211, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/home/ivan/diabetes_django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 710, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/home/ivan/diabetes_django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1322, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/ivan/diabetes_django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1317, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/ivan/diabetes_django/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1287, in to_python
    params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

As the error message says, the empty string is an invalid value for a date. You could either provide a string in the required format, e.g. `"2015-11-04"`, or use python's `date`, e.g. `date.today()`.

However, I'm slightly worried that you have this change in migration `0008` in your migrations. Changing to a custom user in an existing project is *extremely* tricky (see the [warning in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)). If you delete all your user migrations and recreate them, then it should create the model from scratch, and not ask for a default date at all.

Comment: It is my first studieng project, so don't worrie. I  don't understand where in my model need to change default date format.  And I delete all tables, then start migrate again, why I still have exception.

Comment: Make sure you delete your migration files as well, when you restart your database.

Comment: It works. I delete again all migrations and all table in db. Then makemgrations each single app. Thank for you answer